# How can i highlight selected cell's in PSTCollectionview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cell, collectionview, pstcollectionview

Iam using PSTCollection view for grid layout so it will support iOS 5.0 onward ,but when i click one cell its working fine .Iam trying to implement a selection effect like a glow border on selected cell so it will increase user experience.Any one know how to do it in PSTCollectionview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *customCell = (CustomCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //TODO: Customize your cell here
}
```

Comment: when the user select's a cell. the above method is called. U need to access the cell clicked and add the effect u like to the cell. Hope u got it.

Comment: u mean some thing like customCell.background-color?

Comment: Yes u can change the background color or add a overlay view to depict that the cell is selected.